# Remote debugging Beaglebone from a 64 bit machine

Tags: linux, eclipse, beagleboard

I am running Xubuntu on a 64 bit machine. When trying to debug a Beaglebone using gdb (via Eclipse) I get the following error message:

"Remote 'g' packet reply is too long"

See here for more details:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=509479

At the host I am using gdb-multiarch.
When start it, it announces:
"This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu"."

Can you please tell me how to configure GDB to work with a 32 bit target? Any other thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the BeagleBone uses an ARM processor.

You'll have to get the ARM version (more precise: version for debugging ARM processors) of GDB to debug - you cannot do this with the x86 version.

For Windows the ARM version is available in the "WinARM" packet.

Maybe for Linux such a packet does not exist and you'll have to re-compile GDB.

Answer (score 0):

Add "set architecture arm" to the .gdbinit file referenced in Eclipse under Debug Configurations -- Debugger -- GDB command file. Make sure the .gdbinit file can be found at run-time by making sure GDB command file contains full path to file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue trying to set up cross compilation through Eclipse with a Ubuntu 12.04 Host VM running on a Mac connecting to a Beaglebone Black target.  When trying to debug my project, I would get the same "Remote 'g' packet reply is too long" error.  What solved this issue for me was to go into the Debug Configuration for your project, select the Debugger tab, and replace gdb to gdb-multiarch the GDB debugger field.